# Display events by categories for current year, and past 3 years

Tags: wordpress

I am on Wordpress 4.7.5 and CiviCRM 4.7.19. I have tried the CiviEvent Widget but it does not do enough for me. I have tried modifying it but my skills are too beginner.

I would like to display my events by event type on a wordpress page. Then for each event type, I would like to have a past events page where the past events for 2017, 2016 and 2015 are displayed.

Illustration:

**Events page**
Event Type 1
- event
- event
- past events page link
Event Type 2
- event
- event
- past events page link
Event Type 3
- event
- event
- past events page link

**Past Events page for Event type 1**
2017
- event
- event
2016
- event
- event
2015
- event
- event

What I have tried as an alternative: Created event types as post categories, then created years as sub-categories. Then inserted civicrm event as a post under the relevant sub-category. Then I intended to create page templates that display the posts under certain categories. However, I realised that I am unable to filter out the on-going events and past events. In addition, this means that I need to modify the page templates each year to get the id for the new categories. Example, for 2018, I will have to create 3 2018 sub-categories under each event type. I would prefer it to be an auto-thing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an existing way to "auto-thing" this, unfortunately. I think you may need to contract a [CiviCRM partner](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) to develop some custom code for you, or perhaps reach out to the maintainer of the CiviEvent Widget and see if they're willing to take feature requests. (I suspect they'll want to be compensated for that.)